Effects of quantum jitters at the event horizon?
General relativity would seem to have a black hole’s event
horizon be perfectly smooth on even the smallest scales.
Theorists studying black hole event horizons are aware of the
possibility of quantum fluctuations at the event horizon, eg:
Susskind’s “Complexity and Newton’s Laws” https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.12819.pdf.
Ie: That Rs, the radius of a Schwartzschild BH might thus vary
by a tiny delta-Rs through quantum fluctuations on very tiny
scales.
Might this imply that, due to such quantum fluctuations, a particle,
say a graviton, just inside the horizon, might suddenly find itself
just outside the horizon?  And if so, could it propagate out into
the universe?  Or is there a No-go theorem preventing this kind of event?

Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation

Please do not link directly to pdfs.  The preferred approach is to link to the abstract page.

Re: wiki Hawking radiation suggestion..I’ve read wiki’s entry on Hawking Radiation before.  On re-reading it, I
find nothing which relates directly to my original query.  The only
apparent possibility was mention of Ansari’s paper referencing “..fluctuations
of the horizon area..”, regarding Loop Quantum Gravity.  Reviewing this
pdf showed no obvious connection with my query either.  Thanks anyway.

Oddly, I came across mention of what is probably S. Hawking’s final
paper, in which he concludes that black holes, as such, do NOT exist…
ie: no one-way event horizon having a potential of -c^2.  If so, my
query may be irrelevant.
